# Time.scaleTime 0 тормозит анимацию

Tags: c#, unity3d

В аниматоре есть выбор как вопроизводить анимацию, будет ли она зависить от Time.scaleTime, а у меня используеться animation - как можно тут такое же сделать?

Comment: Вообще использование Legaсy (устаревших) систем есть нежелательным в принципе. Тем более, если ты пишешь сейчас игрушку, а не поддерживаешь ее. Но если поставил за цель, то нужно смотреть в сторону "State Machine" ( http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html )

Comment: @Andrew это же С++

Comment: Это паттерн. Паттерн не зависит от языка. Просто пример паттерна кинул на С++. Можешь погуглить примеры паттерна и на шарпе.

Comment: @Andrew т.е. силами юнити это никак?

Comment: Хочешь пользоватся всеми благами современности -- выкинь проводной телефон вместо того что бы жаловатся что там нету FullHD дисплея и спрашивать как это обойти :) Legacy фичами становятся те, которые слишком неоптимальные или имеют другие существенные недостатки. Из коробки такой возможности у animation нету. Ее можно реализовать самому используя "State Machine" паттерн. То есть ввести понятия статусов, и ввести статуы Paused который будет включатся на паузе паралельно до изменения таймскейла на ноль и будет останавливать все анимации подписанные на этот статус.

Comment: @Andrew так просто у меня открываеться меню, которые все кнопки приводит на свои места, но потом мне нужно отдельно кнопку заанимировать, и она не анимируеться, т.к. уже родительський объект держит её в animator т.е. анимация уже не проигрываеться и state заморожен.

Comment: такс.... я не могу с этим помогать т.к. ты банально путаешся в терминологии и путаешь меня. Animator и Animation это совсем разные вещи в юнити. И ты в разные периоды времени говоришь что используешь то одно, то другое. Решись уже  -- чем ты пользуешся для анимации.

Comment: @Andrew, так ведь animator - это и есть стейтмашина, которой нужно управлять из кода, а animation - это анимация, закрепленная за конкретным стейтом, нельзя использовать "то одно, то другое".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Animation - компонент юнити который вообще не обновляется с версии 4.0. То есть легаси. У него меньше возможностей, например  он не саппортит Sprite animation и material properties animation. Ему на замену пришел Animator. Это разные компоненты юнити. При чем он еще в самом вопросе противопоставлял эти два компонента, по контексту же это видно. То есть МОЖНО использовать то одно то другое.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker А учитывая это теперь обрати внимание на сам вопрос: "В аниматоре есть выбор..... а у меня используеться animation". То есть в один момент автор утверждает что он использует animation компонент, а не аниматор. А в другой момент он говорит "т.к. уже родительський объект держит её в animator". То есть здесь он уже аниматор использует. Короче, я с этим вопросом задолбался. Лучше какие-то другие поразбираю